# Why am I getting undefined as an answer when fetching data from an currency exchange API?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch the exchange rate of one currency so that I can use it in my conversion.

```
currenycodes = new Array("USD", "EUR", "INR", "JPY", "RUB", "GBP", "CAD", "MXN", "CNY", "KRW", "BTC", "ETH");
```

This is the codes array from which I find the code which the user wants as the base (the user enters the code and I find its index in the array).

```
var sourcecode = currenycodes[sourceIndex];
var targetcode = currenycodes[targetIndex];
```

After I find the codes the user wants to exchange between (supposed USD to EUR). I feed these codes to the API.

```
var url = `https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/c698605f2b9ef5f1ef716047/latest/${sourcecode}`;

    async function currency() {
            let res = await fetch(url);
            let data = await res.json();
            let val=data.conversion_rates.targetcode;
            console.log(val)
        // console.log(data.conversion_rates.EUR);
    }
```

Here conversion* rate is an array of **key:value pairs** e.g.: {USD: 1, AED: 3.6725, AFN: 85.8224, ALL: 97.9119*}

I need that value for the further conversion process, but I am getting undefined for some reason where the good `data.conversion_rates.EUR` gives perfect value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't do this alone.

Comment: @Daedalus I was taught await doesn't work unless the function is async

Comment: @Daedalus direct call just below, eg: currency()

Comment: @Daedalus no bro, is there any chance the problem is with variable 'targetcode' which is a string I am trying to attach to a response's data?

Comment: `I need that value for the further conversion process, but I am getting undefined for some reason where the good data.conversion_rates.EUR gives perfect value.`: This is IMHO a duplicate to [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name): `let val=data.conversion_rates[targetcode]`. If you agree with that @Zethyst I'll close it as duplicate.

Comment: @t.niese I missed that; I'm going to retract.

Comment: @Daedalus THANKS!! data.conversion_rates[targetcode] worked just fine.

Comment: @Zethyst Thank t.niese; not me.  I went off the wrong track.

Comment: @t.niese THANKSSS MAN. Because of you, my project got completed! https://scalemate.vercel.app/